# Does "spot inspection" make sense?

Tags: expressions

We have a lot of machines located in many places in our site, and we need to define the activity that inspecting the machine running status regularly by plan in field, does the "spot inspection" a nice word to define this activity?

Comment: "On-the-spot checks" or "On-the-spot inspections" would make sense.

Comment: "define the activity that inspecting the machine running status regularly". That would be programmed inspection. Spot inspection is an unscheduled inspection, usually conducted to verify the programmed inspections are being carried out.

Comment: "Spot inspection" is generally used to mean a random, unannounced inspection, as Phil suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Consider calling it a ***regular inspection***. The dictionary entry has an example that includes the usage you describe.

> **Regular** *adjective*
>   2 Recurring at uniform intervals: *a regular monthly check*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/regular?q=regular%20)

As Phil Sweet comments, *spot checks* are not scheduled inspections. As its definition suggests, *spot check* is not an appropriate term for planned inspections.

> **Spot check** *noun*
>   A test made without warning on a randomly selected subject
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spot-check?q=spot%20check)

Comment: I get your point and think better of 'regular inspection' now. Thanks!